# Angular wildcard to match child routes

Tags: angular

Trying to find subroutes with a component

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: CatalogueComponent,
  },
  {
    path: 'search/**',
    component: CatalogueComponent,
  },
  ...
  {
     path: '**',
     redirectTo: '/page-not-found'
  }
}
```

Just can't get it work. **path: 'search/**',** is never matched..

search url is as follows: search/brand=sdfsdf/model=sdfvsdf/page=2

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't be using URLs like you mentioned, the right pattern to use is `search?brand=sdfsdf&model=sdfvsdf&page=2` and then retrieve the query params by injecting `ActivatedRoute` into the `CatalogueComponent`, with either `this.activatedRoute.snapshot.queryParams` or `this.activatedRoute.queryParams.subscribe(params => ...)` if you want to react to the params change which I think is what you need.

Comment: Its sounds good, but its not what SEO guy wants to have... I currently have get params...

Comment: then try `path: 'search/brand=:brand/model=:model/page=:page'` and retrieve them with `this.activatedRoute.params` or `this.activatedRoute.snapshot.params`

Comment: If that doesn't work you'll be forced to use the pattern i mentioned in my answer

Comment: By the way I don't get why your "SEO guy" is not OK with that, Google itself uses this URL pattern